# Let $A\subset\mathbb R$ be a finite set. Proof that $\mathbb N\cup A$ has the WOP.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

I would appreciate it if someone can confirm whether my proof is valid. Please keep in mind that this is a homework problem from a section in (very) elementary number theory, so restrict your suggestions to that.

---

> Suppose $A$ accepts a decomposition into three set partitions $X,Y,Z,$ such that $$X=\{x\in A|x\gt1\},\ Y=\{y\in A|y\lt1\},\ Z=\{z\in A|x=1\}.$$ Since $A$ is finite, then its partitions are finite. So $X=\{x_{i}\}_{i=1,...,n}$, $Y=\{y_{i}\}_{i=1,...,m}$, $Z=\{1\}$.
>
> $\mathbb N\cup Z=\mathbb N$, and by the WOP it has a least element, i.e 1.
>
> For  $X$ we have that $\forall_{i=1,...,n}(x_{i}\gt1)$, so $\text{min}[(\mathbb N\cup Z)\cup X=\text{min}(\mathbb N\cup X)=1.$
>
> For $Y$ we have that $\forall_{i=1,...,m}(y_{i}\lt1)$. Consider $j\gt i\implies a_{j}\gt a_{i}$. Then we can see that $$y_{1}\lt y_{2}\lt ...\lt y_{m-1}\lt y_{m}\lt 1,$$so $Y$ has a least element, $y_{1}\lt 1$. Then $$\text{min}(\mathbb N\cup Y)=\text{min}[(\mathbb N\cup Z)\cup Y]=\text{min}([(\mathbb N\cup Z)\cup X]\cup Y)=y_{1}.$$But $$[(\mathbb N\cup Z)\cup X]\cup Y=\mathbb N\cup (Z\cup X\cup Y)=\mathbb N\cup A,$$therefore $\mathbb N\cup A$ satisfies the WOP.
>
> Moreover, if $A$ accepts a smaller decompostion, then the minimal element of the union $\mathbb N\cup A$ will be the least of the minimal elements of the sets united.
>
> ---

Comment: I'm sorry, you haven't even addressed the task that needs to be done, because you didn't pay attention to to definition of the well ordering property, which requires you to take an *arbitrary* subset $S$ of your set $\mathbb N \cup A$, and show that $S$ has a least element.  And the partition idea is not helpful for this.  Please start over.

Comment: If you mean the "well ordering property", call it the "well ordering property". The word "wop" is an ethnic slur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this *harder* problem will guide you to an *easier* solution.

> Suppose $A$ and $B$ are two well ordered subsets of $\mathbb R$.  Then $A \cup B$ is also well ordered.

Proof:  Let $S$ be an arbitrary subset of $A \cup B$. If $S \subseteq A$ or $S \subseteq B$ then $S$ has a least element because $A$ and $B$ are well ordered.  So assume otherwise.
Then $S = (S \cap A) \cup (S \cap B)$, with both $S \cap A$ and $S \cap B$ non empty.   Since $A$ is well ordered, $S \cap A$ has a minimum $a$, and likewise, since $B$ is well ordered, $S \cap B$ has a minimum $b$.  Let $m = \min(a, b)$.  The claim is that $m = \min(S)$.

First $m \in S$ since $a, b \in S$.  Second, let $s \in S$.  Then either $s \in A$ or $s \in B$.  If $s \in A$, we have $m \le a \le s$, since $a = \min(S \cap A)$.  If $s \in B$ then $m \le b \le s$, since $b = \min(S \cap B)$. This shows that $m = \min(S)$.

Note:  Say two totally ordered sets are *order isomorphic* if there is an order preserving bijection between them.  Check that if two sets are order isomorphic, one is well ordered if and only if the other is well ordered.
Not every well ordered subset of the reals is order isomorphic to the set of integers. For example, let $A = \{1 - 1/n : n \ge 1\}$ and $B = \{2 - 1/n : n \ge 1\}$. Then $A$ and $B$ are both order isomorphic to $\mathbb N$, and hence well ordered. Their union $A \cup B$ is well ordered but not order isomorphic to $\mathbb N$.

Comment: I posted my attempt as an answer. Would you be so kind as to tell me whether it's wrong or missing anything?

Answer (score -1):

Let $A$ be a finite subset of $\mathbb R$ with cardinality of $n$. Then its elements are countable, and we can index $A$ with a subset of $\mathbb N$, i.e the set  $\{1,...,n\}$. Let us perform this indexing, in a way such that $i\lt j\implies a_{i}\lt a_{j}$ ($A=\{a_{i}\}_{i=1,...,n})$. Then, since $\lt$ is a total ordering relation on $\mathbb R$, we get $$a_{1}\lt a_{2}\lt...a_{n-1}\lt a_{n}.$$ And we can see that $A$, and any subset of $A$, will have a least element. Moreover, we can conclude that any finite subset of $\mathbb R$ is well ordered by the $\lt$ relation.

---

> Let $S$ denote the set union $\mathbb N\cup A$, where $A$ denotes some finite subset of $\mathbb R$. Now let $S$ be indexed by $\mathbb N$, in a way such that $i\lt j\implies a_{i}\lt a_{j}$ and, moreover, $a_{i}=a_{j}\implies i=j$, so $S=\{s_{i}\}_{i\in\mathbb N}$.
>
> For example, let $A$ be the set $\{-1,1,\phi,e,\pi\}$. Then, $$\mathbb N\cup A=\{s_{1}=-1,s_{2}=1,s_{3}=\phi,s_{4}=2,s_{5}=e,s_{6}=3,s_{7}=\pi,s_{8}=4,,s_{9}=5,...\}.$$ In general we then have, $$s_{1}\lt s_{2}\lt s_{3}\lt s_{4}\lt ...$$ To show how this indexing is possible, first let us take $a_{1}$, the least element from $A$.
>
> If $(\mathbb N\cap\{a_{1}\})=\varnothing$, we should then be able to find $n_{i}\in\mathbb N$ such that $n_{i}\lt a_{1}\lt n_{i+1}$ (since $\mathbb N$ contains *all* numbers). We then arrange $a_{1}$ into $\mathbb N$ as the $(i+1)^{\text{th}}$ term, in a way such that, $$\mathbb N\cup\{a_{1}\}=\{1,2,...,n_{i},a_{1},n_{i+1},...\}.$$ If at any point $(\mathbb N\cap\{a_{i}\})=\{a_{i}\}$, we then notice that $\exists_{k=1,2,...}:a_{i}=n_{k}$, so $\mathbb N\cup\{a_{i}\}=\mathbb N$, and we proceed with $a_{i+1}$.
>
> Next, we find $n_{j}$ such that $n_{j}\lt a_{2}\lt n_{j+1}$. If $n_{j}=n_{i}$, then (since $a_{1}\gt a_{2}$), we arrange $a_{2}$ into $\mathbb N\cup\{a_{1}\}$, in a way such that, $$\mathbb N\cup\{a_{1},a_{2}\}=\{1,2,...,n_{i},a_{1},a_{2},n_{i+1},...\}.$$ Otherwise (if $n_{j}\not=n_{i}$), we find $n_{j}\ge n_{i+1}$, and we arrange $a_{2}$ into $\mathbb N\cup\{a_{1}\}$, in a manner such that, $$\mathbb N\cup\{a_{1},a_{2}\}=\{1,2,...,n_{i},a_{1},...,a_{2},n_{j+1},...\}.$$
>
> Once we have gone through all $a_{i}\in A$, by using $\mathbb N$ to index  $(\mathbb N\cup A)$ such that $(\mathbb N\cup A)=S=\{s_{i}\}_{i\in\mathbb N}$, we'll get that, $$s_{1}\lt s_{2}\lt s_{3}\lt ...$$ as desired.
>
> ---
>
> We will now show that every non-empty subset of $\mathbb N\cup A$ has a least element.
>
> *Proof.* $\ $ Suppose $B$ is a subset of the union $\mathbb N\cup A$ such that it does not contain a least element, that is to say, $\forall x\in B\exists y\in B: y\lt x$. Also let $C$ denote the set containing all the lower bounds of B, that is to say, $\forall x\in B\exists y\in C:y\le x$.
>
> Then $s_{1}\not\in B$ (for otherwise it'd be minimal), so $s_{1}\in C$. Now suppose $s_{n}$ is in C, and consider $s_{n+1}$.
>
> If $s_{n+1}$ were not in $C$, then there would exist $x$ in B, $x_{0}$ say, such that $x_{0}\lt s_{n+1}$. It would follow that $x_{0}\le s_{n}$. But $x_{0}$ cannot be less than a lower bound of the set that contains it, so, forcibly, $x_{0}=s_{n}$ ($B\cap C=\{x_{0}\}$). However, from this it'd follow that $x_{0}$ is the least element of $B-$ contradiction.
>
> Hence, it must be the case that $s_{n+1}$ is in $C$, and, by induction, $C=\mathbb N\cup A$. Thus $B=\varnothing$.
>
> It is proved then, by contraposition, that $$B\subset (\mathbb N\cup A)\land B\not=\varnothing \implies B\text{ contains a least element.}$$$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 
>  \blacksquare$

I think the following proof is what @fredgoodman was looking for, however:

> $C\subset (\mathbb N\cup A)\land C\not=\varnothing \implies C\text{ contains a least element.}$
>
> *Proof.*$\ $ Suppose $B$ contains no least element, and let $C=(\mathbb N\cup A)\text{\ }B.$ Since $B$ contains no least element, $s_{1}\not\in B$ and therefore $s_{1}\in C$. Then it follows that the statement, $$(\{k:k\lt s_{1}\})\implies s_{1}\in C$$ holds since the consequent is true.
>
> Suppose, for some $s_{n}\gt s_{1},\ \{k:k\lt s_{n}\}=\{s_{1},s_{2},...,s_{n-1}\}\subset C$. Then $s_{1},s_{2},...,s_{n-1}$ are not in $B$. Therefore $s_{n}\not\in B$ (for otherwise it'd be minimal). Therefore $s_{n}\in C$. It follows then, by complete induction, that $C=(\mathbb N\cup A)$. But $C=(\mathbb N\cup A)\text{\ }B$, so therefore $B=\varnothing$.
>
> It is proved then, by contraposition, that $$B\subset (\mathbb N\cup A)\land B\not=\varnothing \implies B\text{ contains a least element.}$$$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 
>  \blacksquare$

Comment: OK, it's true that the finite subset is well ordered.  But you have to prove that the union of two well ordered sets is also well ordered.

Comment: @fredgoodman The part in yellow doesn’t prove that?

Comment: I'm sorry, I misread it.   I think the intuition is absolutely correct.  I'm not sure if I believe it yet as an argument, I have to think some more.  The last sentence is neither justified by what goes before, nor is it needed, if you want to proceed according to this strategy, which is different from what I had in mind.

Comment: OK, I thought a little more.  Your intuition is correct, but I think your argument is actually wrong for the following reason.  You are effectively assuming what you want to prove.  How would you arrange $S$ into a sequence $s_i$ such that $s_i < s_j$ iff $i < j$?  Presumably you would say, let $s_1$ be the least element and let $s_2$ be the least element of $S \setminus \{s_1\}$, $s_3$ the least element of $S \setminus \{s_1, s_2\}$, etc.    Do you have another way to do this?  Do you see that you are assuming the well ordering property in order to prove it?

Comment: @fredgoodman I think I understand. Does my update fix this assumption?

Comment: There were two "obvious" points that you had to justify to carry out your strategy (1)  $A \cup \mathbb N$ can be arranged in a sequence $s_1 < s_2 < s_3 < .\dots$, and (2)  This implies $A \cup \mathbb N$ is well ordered.   You have taken care of the second point, and your proof is the same as the proof that the principle of induction for the integers implies the integers are well ordered.  (We can get back to this later, and observe that it doesn't actually have to be done a second time.)

Comment: There is still the first point to be taken care of. How to do (1)? How do you even choose/find $s_1$?

Comment: @fredgoodman It'll be just a minute now, please. I'm typing it up.

Comment: If I may dare to interrupt you, please ONLY tell me how to choose $s_1$.  Or, if you must, $s_1$ and $s_2$.  What I would like to prevent is that the selection of $s_2$ involves two cases.

Comment: @fredgoodman Okay, what do you think now?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68345/discussion-between-fredgoodman-and-ivlivs-caesar).